# CSS spacing - using tailwinds

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have an unordered list with 4 list items. I want to move the fist item a little to the right and then leave it there but the other 3 items I want them to have more space. How would I achieve this in css.

```
<ul className="mx-8 flex">
  <li>&copy;2022 Airoflair</li>
  <li>Cookie Policy</li>
  <li>Refund Policy</li>
  <li>Privacy Policy</li>
  <li>terms & Conditions</li>
</ul>
```

So far this is my css:

```
li {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tailwind css you can add the padding left class.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding
the p is for padding, the l if for left side and the 8 is for how much padding, the docs link also specifies how to use a custom amount of padding

```
<ul className="mx-8 flex">
   <li class="pl-8">&copy;2022 Airoflair</li>
   <li>Cookie Policy</li>
   <li>Refund Policy</li>
   <li>Privacy Policy</li>
   <li>terms & Conditions</li>
</ul>
```

and then without tailwind you could get the same result by changing the style like

```
<ul className="mx-8 flex">
    <li style="padding-left: 2rem;">&copy;2022 Airoflair</li>
    <li>Cookie Policy</li>
    <li>Refund Policy</li>
    <li>Privacy Policy</li>
    <li>terms & Conditions</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use pseudo-classes: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#pseudo-classes. This will only affect the first child.

```
<ul className="mx-8 flex first:pl-8">
    <li>&copy;2022 Airoflair</li>
    <li>Cookie Policy</li>
    <li>Refund Policy</li>
    <li>Privacy Policy</li>
    <li>terms & Conditions</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to use `flex` in this case . Make two `<span>` and put the first `li` in the first span and the rest four `li` in the second span.

Add the `flex` in the first span.

Now in the second span again add the class `flex` (nested) to make them in row and `space-x-8` to make the spacing between the 4 `<li>s`.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<ul class=" flex justify-around text-[10px]">
  <span>
  <li>&copy;2022 Airoflair</li>
  </span>
  <span class="flex space-x-8">
  <li>Cookie Policy</li>
  <li>Refund Policy</li>
  <li>Privacy Policy</li>
  <li>terms & Conditions</li>
  </span>
</ul>
```

I suggest you to add `text-[30px]` tailwind class instead of using CSS.